# How do I start Apache Tomcat at boot on Mac OS X?

Tags: tomcat, mac-osx

I observed that there is no full guide for installing tomcat on OS X that will include setting it up to start at boot time.

Here is the quick guide:

- install [macports](http://www.macports.org/)

  - `suport port upgrade`
  - `sudo port upgrade outdated`.
- `sudo port install tomcat6`, or if you want other version check `port list|grep tomcat`
- config is now at: `/opt/local/share/java/tomcat6/conf`
- startup script: `/opt/local/share/java/tomcat6/bin/tomcatctl`

  cp /opt/local/share/java/tomcat6/conf/tomcat-users.xml.sample /opt/local/share/java/tomcat6/conf/tomcat-users.xml
  nano /opt/local/share/java/tomcat6/conf/tomcat-users.xml
- ... [check article](http://mikevalentiner.wordpress.com/2009/01/30/how-to-install-and-run-tomcat-on-macos/)

But **I'm missing the part on how to make it run as true service/daemon: at system startup and optionally to make it restart if it does crash.**

Comment: Why use MacPorts when they have official binaries available? I hate the reliance some Mac users have for MacPorts, especially when most MacPorts packages are out of date and thus you open yourself up to security holes.

Comment: Simon, this is required because macports is also a package manager so you'll get over a lot of problems using this way. Also you will be able to upgrade tomcat very easy.

Answer (score 14):

This is for installing tomcat as a **daemon** on port 8080 but enable also port 80 by using a firewall redirection. It was tested on Mac OS 10.6 but should work also with 10.5.

Edit `/opt/local/share/java/tomcat6/conf/server.xml` and add `proxyport="80" URIEncoding="UTF-8"` inside `<Connector .../>`.

For **forwarding port** 80 to 8080 run this line and add it do `/bin/catalina.sh`:

```
sudo ipfw add 100 fwd 127.0.0.1,8080 tcp from any to any 80 in
```

Assign **enough memory** to the Java machine or you may be in trouble later.
Inside `/opt/local/share/java/tomcat6/conf/local.env`

```
export JAVA_JVM_VERSION=CurrentJDK
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx3000M -Xms3000M -Djava.awt.headless=true -Duser.timezone=UTC"
```

In my example I allocated ~3Gb or RAM but you can adapt this, anyway don't put less than 1GB if you are running `hudson` inside tomcat.

## Running as a service

Run `nano /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.tomcat.plist` and paste the code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"     "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>org.apache.tomcat</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
            <string>/opt/local/share/java/tomcat6/bin/catalina.sh</string>
            <string>run</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Check that launchd detected you new daemon, if not reboot :(

```
launchctl list|grep tomcat
```

Start tomcat manually.

```
launchctl start org.apache.tomcat
```

If the status is something else than `-`, you have a problem and you should investigate it: `launchctl log level debug` and check `/var/log/system.log`.

Comment: Could be me as I'm new to Mac (OS X 10.8.2) but I had to do: sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.tomcat.plist  to get it to start

Comment: I haven't had it working until I made the file's owner `root`. So, when editing the file type `sudo nano /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.tomcat.plist`

Answer (score 1):

You need to register tomcat as an item that needs to be executed on startup. On Mac OS, this is handled by launchd (http://developer.apple.com/macosx/launchd.html). I don't know if launchd supports auto restarting, but otherwise you should have a look at something like supervisord (http://supervisord.org/).

Comment: Yes, launchd has a keepalive option, both as yes/no and with four optional conditions.

Answer (score 1):

For Snow Leopard launch on startup I created a plist file in /Library/LaunchDaemons/   The plist file will look like this (below, amend to match your directories).  You can start/stop the service for testing by issuing  "launchctl load org.macports.tomcat6.plist" or "launchctl unload org.macports.tomcat6.plist".  Once you have it working reboot to prove the autostart at boot.

---

```
sh-3.2# more org.macports.tomcat6.plist
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd" >
<plist version='1.0'>
<dict>
<key>Label</key><string>org.macports.tomcat6</string>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
        <string>/opt/local/bin/daemondo</string>
        <string>--label=tomcat6</string>
        <string>--start-cmd</string>
        <string>/opt/local/bin/tomcatctl</string>
        <string>start</string>
        <string>;</string>
        <string>--pid=fileclean</string>
        <string>--pidfile</string>
        <string>/opt/local/share/java/tomcat6/logs/tomcat6.pid</string>
</array>
<key>Debug</key><false/>
<key>Disabled</key><false/>
<key>OnDemand</key><false/>
<key>RunAtLoad></key><true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```